# Influx 2.0 CLI Client Not Connecting

Tags: macos, docker, influxdb

I'm having a problem connecting to a remote instance of Influx 2.0 OSS using the influx client.

First, I'm pretty sure it's not the server:

```
curl http://192.168.1.7:8086/health
{"name":"influxdb", "message":"ready for queries and writes", "status":"pass", "checks":[], "version": "2.0.7", "commit": "2a45f0c037"}
```

I have a config set, when I try to use it to ping the server:

```
❯ influx config
Active  Name            URL                     Org
*       myinfluxd     http://192.168.1.7        my_org
❯ influx ping
Error: Invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value.
Error: Invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value.
See 'influx ping -h' for help
```

Other commands also don't work

```
❯ influx query 'show databases;'
Error: Failed to read metadata: missing expected annotation datatype.
Error: Invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value.
See 'influx query -h' for help
```

I'm using the client on a Mac with BigSur (installed with homebrew), the client version and server version are the same (2.0.7).

Client

```
❯ influx version
Influx CLI 2.0.7 (git: none) build_date: 2021-07-02T03:23:38Z
```

Server

```
❯ influx version
Influx CLI 2.0.7 (git: none) build_date: 2021-07-02T03:23:38Z
```

```
root@influxdb2:/# influx config                                                                            
Active  Name    URL                     Org                                                                
*       default http://localhost:8086   my_org
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. Too bad we haven't seen a solution here. Did you figure it out?

Comment: try with newer version, say, 2.4.0? I tried but couldn't reproduce such issue.